# conditional get_or_create Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two model `User` and `Post`.

`Post` has an attribute `status` with which will be either `draft` or `published`.

I want to make sure that `User` has only one post with published `status`.

Is there anything built in rails that does this ? like get_or_create based on a condition?

Comment: There is a method called `find_or_create_by`, maybe that's something that can help you

Comment: I tried `find_or_create_by_status('published')` but didn't work.

Comment: `find_or_create_by(status: 'published')` is the correct syntax

Comment: Great, I made an answer to wrap things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method called [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) which looks up a record in the db by the given criteria and returns it or creates a new one if no record exists.

An example

```
u = User.find_or_create_by(status: 'published')
```